# numbering unique values in a column

Tags: count, awk, unique, sas

I have a file where column one has a list of family identifiers

```
AB
AB
AB
AB
SAR
SAR
EAR
```

is there a way that I can create a new column where each repeat is numbered creating a new label for each repeat i.e.

```
AB_1
AB_2
AB_3
AB_4
SAR_1
SAR_2
EAR_1
```

I am able to do this in SAS but am looking for a bash option (possibly awk)

```
data file;
set file; 
count+1;
by name;
if first.name then count=1;
new_name=compress(name||'_'||count);
run;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk '{print $1"_"++a[$1]}' file
AB_1
AB_2
AB_3
AB_4
SAR_1
SAR_2
EAR_1
```

Comment: @user1598034 great, don't forgot to upvote and **[accept this answer by clicking the tick mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)** next to it.

Answer (score 2):

try this one-liner:

```
awk '{a[$0]++;print $0"_"a[$0]}' file
```

with your input data:

```
kent$ echo "AB
AB
AB
AB
SAR
SAR
EAR"|awk '{a[$0]++;print $0"_"a[$0]}'
AB_1
AB_2
AB_3
AB_4
SAR_1
SAR_2
EAR_1
```